# MathJax editing preview improvements userscript

Tags: discussion, mathjax, user-scripts

There have been a number of issues recently with how MathJax interacts with the editing preview code:

- [MathJax preview bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275997/mathjax-preview-bug)
- [MathJax not rendering in previews](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22554/mathjax-not-rendering-in-previews)
- [Problems with losing MathJax formatting previews while creating question or answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22551/problems-with-losing-mathjax-formatting-previews-while-creating-question-or-answ?lq=1)
- https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/mathjax-not-rendering

and there are some older issues that have been in play for a while:

- [MathJax preview broken when equations contain `\label`s](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/mathjax-preview-broken-when-equations-contain-labels?rq=1)
- [MathJax makes preview flicker](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9736/mathjax-makes-preview-flicker?rq=1)
- [Only view MathJax in preview on button press](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19773/only-view-mathjax-in-preview-on-button-press)
- [Introducing a delay for updating the post preview box](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21272/introducing-a-delay-for-updating-the-post-preview-box?rq=1)
- [Would it be possible to not have the post-preview process ALL of the latex as you type?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21915/would-it-be-possible-to-not-have-the-post-preview-process-all-of-the-latex-as-yo)

Some of these are due to the code used by the preview editor not staying up-to-date with the new features of MathJax.  Others are feature requests that have not been implemented.

I have written a user script that patches the editing code to resolve these issues by handling the new features more appropriately during editing, and by adding new interface checkboxes to control MathJax typesetting.

> [<kbd>Get the user script</kbd>](https://stackapps.com/questions/6864/stackexchange-mathjax-editing-improvements)

The new editing code is being evaluated by the StackExchange team, so it may not be necessary to use the user script in the long run, but you can give it a try now and see how it works for you.  That would also help beta-test the changes.

**EDIT 1**:  I've posted a new version of the user script that fixes some problems that were found during testing.  If you have installed the script, you should get the new version.

**EDIT 2**: The changes from this user script (other than the checkboxes to control MathJax and error messages) are [now available on math.se and meta.math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23019/mathjax-editing-updates-beta?cb=1), so this script is no longer needed unless you want the checkboxes.

Comment: This might be related, but in some comments I see blank boxes instead of MathJax output. This changes when I vote a comment, but still it shouldn't be like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I haven't heard anything like that before.  Can you post a more complete description of the problem (e.g., whether it is repeatable, and if so where, plus a screen shot, and what browser you are using, etc.) as a new meta post?

Comment: Alright. I'll do that later.

Comment: @DavideCervone, I am still experiencing the error, when a preview of an answer is not rendered properly. I use Chrome if it matters.

Comment: @schatten, can you be more specific about what you mean by "the error"?  And what "not rendering properly" consists of?

Comment: @DavideCervone Just tried again, and it worked. I have restarted my Chrome browser since the first time I saw the issue. The issue was this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275997/mathjax-preview-bug

Comment: @schatten, OK, glad that was all it was, and thanks for the additional data.