# MathJax editing updates beta

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editor

There have been a lot of complaints and bug reports about the state of the $ MathJax $ editing experience all around SE lately. We've heard you, and with a lot of help from the kind folks from $ MathJax $ (a special [shout out](https://gist.github.com/dpvc/c5a3f1be98a7eb342ba1e2da0284c82b/revisions) goes to [Davide](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7798/davide-cervone)), things are finally moving along.

Today we're rolling out a beta version of the $ MathJax $, PageDown and Markdown integration on meta.math.SE and math.SE, that addresses a bunch of issues. We chose math.SE, because it already proved to be helpful with $ MathJax $ issues in the past (it is the only site that runs on the latest beta.mathjax.org bits).

So please be extra mindful of any $ MathJax $ issues you may encounter in the following days, and please report any bugs here on [meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug+mathjax).

[image: moar mathjax]

$P.S.$
Don't forget to disable the editing preview userscripts

$P.S. 2$
Here's a short list of fixes, provided by Davide:

- disabled the fast preview during editing
- <strike>disabled the assistive MathML during editing</strike>
- processSectionDelay = 0 during editing reduces the flickering and speeds up refreshes slightly
- disabling the noErrors extension during editing, so that actual error messages appear
- allow the editor to interrupt MathJax
- add support for CommonHMTL for the best results
- reset the `\label{}` data before each typeset to prevent multiple-defined label errors

#### Update

The changes from this beta graduated network-wide in build rev `2016.4.25.3507`

Comment: I guess this is better than Al Pacino shouting ***"YOU'RE OUT OF MATHJAX! YOU'RE OUT OF MATHJAX! THIS WHOLE COURTROOM IS OUT OF MATHJAX!!!"***

Comment: OOPS, there was an error on my list.  This doesn't actually disable the assistive MathML extension (since after you stop typing, you might want to use your screen reader on the typeset version).  Users are still allowed to disable it themselves in the MathJax contextual menu.

Comment: Just enabled this network wide, before graduating it / replacing old code entirely.

Comment: @DavideCervone Do you want bug reports here, or do you also follow other metas? [mathjax broken for no-braces superscript + subscript](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/mathjax-broken-for-no-braces-superscript-subscript)

Comment: @Gilles, I think you should create new meta posts for any issues with the editing code, since the code is now active everywhere, unless mosa disagrees.  I do follow the MathJax tag on all sites, so I will get daily notification of new posts with that tag.  As for the item on the CS site, that is not related to this update (see my post there).

Answer (score 3):

For offline editing on OS X,
for math.SE,
I am using MacDown
from
http://macdown.uranusjr.com/.

I find this extremely useful.
I can grab an in-process answer
on math.SE, continue with
MacDown offline,
and copy and paste it back
on math.SE when done.

I have not had a problem yet.

(My apologies if this is
not appropriate as an answer here.)

Comment: Meh, it's beta. Appropriate enough.